# Syntax Error in raw MySQL query in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am using raw mysql queries in django with limit (The limit is dynamic and to be mentioned in Url) such as.

```
cursor.execute("some select query limit %s " , [limit_value] )
```

This limit value is comes from the URL `www.asd.com/qwe/?limit=5`  and I catch this value as  `limit_value=request.GET.get('limit')`  and when i print this limit value it will print 5 means I can get the limit value from URL but when I mentioned it in select query as I have shown above. It will throw the error

> (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''5'' at line 1")

But if I mentioned limit value in file as `limit_value=5` and use it in select query as I have shown above it will work.

So it means limit in select query will not work if I mentioned it in URL and catch it into file. WHY? Or there is anything I am missing?

My query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    A.entity_id AS entity_id, 
    A.email AS email,
    A.catquizid AS style_quiz_score,
    A.catquizquesans AS style_quiz_answer,
    A.created_at AS date_joined,
    A.is_active AS is_active,
    B.attribute_id AS attribute_id,
    B.value AS info
FROM customer_entity AS A
inner join  customer_entity_varchar AS B on A.entity_id=B.entity_id 
WHERE B.attribute_id
limit %s
```

Comment: your query formation seems to be wrong , what query do you want to execute

Comment: ok I edit my question but if when i mention the limit in file not in url then same query will work

Comment: I have edited my question please look at that

Comment: `WHERE B.attribute_id ` check here.... `WHERE B.attribute_id  =<some_value>`

Comment: Parameterized queries should be immutable. you want `cur.execute("sql %s", (param,))`

Comment: @Hiroto: That hardly matters here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `limit_value` is a string, not an integer, and as a SQL parameter it is thus given quotes.

Try this:

```
cursor.execute("some select query limit %s", (int(limit_value),))
```